# How can I fill NaN values in a dataframe with the average of the values above it?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking to make it so that NaN values in a dataframe are filled in by the mean of all the values up to that point, as such:

```
  A       
0 1
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 5
5 NaN  
6 NaN
7 11
8 NaN
```

Would become

```
 A       
0 1
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 5
5 3
6 3
7 11
8 4
```

Comment: By 'values above it' you mean all values (including filled NaNs), non-NaN values, or the values between the last NaN and itself?

Comment: including filled NaNs.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it by running the following code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
  "A": [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, pd.NA, pd.NA, 11, pd.NA ]
})

for idx in df[pd.isna(df["A"])].index:
    df.loc[idx, "A"] = np.mean(df.loc[ : idx, "A" ])
```

It iterates on each NaN and fills it with the mean of the previous values, including those filled NaNs.

At the end you will have:

```
>>> df
    A
0   1
1   2
2   3
3   4
4   5
5   3
6   3
7  11
8   4
```

**EDIT**

As stated by RichieV, performance may be an issue with this solution (its runtime complexity is `O(N^2)`) when there are many NaNs, but we also should avoid python iterations, since they are slow when compared to native pandas / numpy calls.

Here is an optimized version:

```
last_idx = None
cumsum = 0
cumnum = 0

for idx in df[pd.isna(df["A"])].index:
    prev_values = df.loc[ last_idx : idx, "A" ]
    # for some reason, pandas includes idx on the slice, so we remove it
    prev_values = prev_values[ : -1 ]
    cumsum += prev_values.sum()
    cumnum += len(prev_values) 
    df.loc[idx, "A"] = int(cumsum / cumnum)
    last_idx = idx
```

Result:

```
>>> df
    A
0   1
1   2
2   3
3   4
4   5
5   3
6   3
7  11
8   4
```

Since in the worst case the script should pass on the dataframe twice, the runtime complexity is now `O(N)`.

Answer (score 1):

Marco's answer works fine but it can be optimized with [incremental average formulas](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/106700/815010), from math.stackexchange.com

Here is an adaptation of that other question (not the exact formula, just the concept).

```
cumsum = 0
expanding_mean = []
for i, xi in enumerate(df['A']):
    if pd.isna(xi):
        mean = cumsum / i # divide by number of items up to previous row
        expanding_mean.append(mean)
        cumsum += mean
    else:
        cumsum += xi

df.loc[df['A'].isna(), 'A'] = expanding_mean
```

The main advantage with this code is not having to read all items up to the current index on each iteration to get the mean.

This option still uses a python loop--which is not the best choice with pandas--but there seems to be no way around it for this use case (hopefully someone will get inspired by this and find such method without a loop).

---

**Performance tests**

Three alternative functions were defined:

- `incremental`: My answer.
- `from_origin`: Marco's original answer.
- `incremental_pandas`: Marco's updated answer.

Tests were done using `timeit` module with 3 repetitions on random samples with 0.4 probability of NaN.

[image]

Full code for testing

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import timeit
import collections
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


def incremental(df: pd.DataFrame):
    # error handling
    if pd.isna(df.iloc[0, 0]):
        df.iloc[0, 0] = 0
    
    cumsum = 0
    expanding_mean = []
    for i, xi in enumerate(df['A']):
        if pd.isna(xi):
            mean = cumsum / i # divide by number of items up to previous row
            expanding_mean.append(mean)
            cumsum += mean
        else:
            cumsum += xi
    df.loc[df['A'].isna(), 'A'] = expanding_mean
    return df

def incremental_pandas(df: pd.DataFrame):
    # error handling
    if pd.isna(df.iloc[0, 0]):
        df.iloc[0, 0] = 0

    last_idx = None
    cumsum = 0
    cumnum = 0
    for idx in df[pd.isna(df["A"])].index:
        prev_values = df.loc[ last_idx : idx, "A" ]
        # for some reason, pandas includes idx on the slice, so we remove it
        prev_values = prev_values[ : -1 ]
        cumsum += prev_values.sum()
        cumnum += len(prev_values) 
        df.loc[idx, "A"] = cumsum / cumnum
        last_idx = idx
        
    return df

def from_origin(df: pd.DataFrame):
    # error handling
    if pd.isna(df.iloc[0, 0]):
        df.iloc[0, 0] = 0

    for idx in df[pd.isna(df["A"])].index:
        df.loc[idx, "A"] = np.mean(df.loc[ : idx, "A" ])

    return df


def get_random_sample(n, p):
    np.random.seed(123)
    return pd.DataFrame({'A': 
        np.random.choice(list(range(10)) + [np.nan],
            size=n, p=[(1 - p) / 10] * 10 + [p])})


r = 3
p = 0.4 # portion of NaNs

# check result from all functions
results = []
for func in [from_origin, incremental, incremental_pandas]:
    random_df = get_random_sample(1000, p)
    new_df = random_df.copy(deep=True)
    results.append(func(new_df))

print('Passed' if all(np.allclose(r, results[0]) for r in results[1:])
    else 'Failed', 'implementation test')



timings = {}
for n in np.geomspace(10, 10000, 10):
    random_df = get_random_sample(int(n), p)
    timings[n] = collections.defaultdict(float)
    results = {}
    for func in ['incremental', 'from_origin', 'incremental_pandas']:
        timings[n][func] = (
            timeit.timeit(f'{func}(random_df.copy(deep=True))', number=r, globals=globals())
            / r
        )

timings = pd.DataFrame(timings).T
print(timings)

timings.plot()
plt.xlabel('size of array')
plt.ylabel('avg runtime (s)')
plt.ylim(0)
plt.grid(True)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
plt.close('all')
```

Comment: Just added a solution that runs in `O(N)`, please include it on the performance tests :)

Comment: @Marco see the performance tests, please validate the code I used for your solutions and do let me know if I made a mistake... I thought your update would perform a lot better.

Comment: I tried investigating what was causing the slowdown and here https://pastebin.com/vqYLR6fC is a line profile of the function (n=10000, p=0.4). It looks like slicing by indices via `.loc` is very slow, so I switched to a solution using numpy only. Here is the line profile (https://pastebin.com/aVbn81K9) for the numpy version. Still, the `sum` call was slow and it did not reach the pure-python (https://pastebin.com/YWqyktwC) performance. I think this is an example where simple is better :)